# Disable Wi-Fi power management on AC power only?

Tags: fedora, wifi, power-management

Fedora 36, KDE Plasma.

So, I find that my 5 GHz Wi-Fi connection is somewhat faster when I disable Wi-Fi power management with "sudo iw wlp0s20f3 set power_save off".

I also see a few ways bandied about of making this setting permanent. But I don't want to affect battery life when I use the battery. I want to disable the power management only on AC power.

In the KDE Plasma power management settings I see a way to run a script when on AC power and when on battery. I could do the change with this script - except for the required "sudo".

Should I do this the old way, tweaking /etc/sudoers to allow the specific commands "sudo iw wlp0s20f3 set power_save off" and "sudo iw wlp0s20f3 set power_save on" without a password? Or should I use some other, better way to disable Wi Fi power management on AC power?

Thanks!